# Android Room Library and Encryption combination

Tags: android, encryption, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am using room library to store my data, and my restriction is i cannot have api level below 22.
Now I am having an attribute which i have to encrypt as this is having some sensitive data.

I have successfully implemented encryption on simple strings but in room we are storing a list directly into database.
Till now i have tried AES and RSA both on a simple string.

Is there any approach available by which without creating extra objects i can encrypt my whole attribute in db.

PS: `SQLCipher` is a heavy call hence i am not using that too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62589479/4694013

Answer (score 2):

You can Use SQLCipher. Its supports Room Database. Check Below Link.

> SQLCipher for Android has a SupportFactory class in the net.sqlcipher.database package that can be used to configure Room to use SQLCipher for Android.

[Using SQLCipher for Android With Room](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher#using-sqlcipher-for-android-with-room)

Answer (score 1):

CWAC-SafeRoom is good library and now support AndroidX.

[CWAC-SafeRoom](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-saferoom)

Comment: See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-saferoom/issues/42. My problem is Locale ORDER BY.