# How to secure encrypt Room database?

Tags: java, android, database

So I encrypted my database with  [cwac_saferoom][1] using this code below
but anytime i run it, i get the exception

Caused by: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is not a database: , while compiling: select count(*) from sqlite_master;

````
public static Database getDatabase(final Context context) {

        SafeHelperFactory.Options options = SafeHelperFactory.Options.builder().setPreKeySql(PREKEY_SQL).build();
        SafeHelperFactory factory= SafeHelperFactory.fromUser(new SpannableStringBuilder(PASSPHRASE), options);

        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (Database.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            Database.class, "solarfinaDatabase")
                            .openHelperFactory(factory)
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }```

what am expecting is a database that is secured so as to avoid data penetration from my APK.


  [1]: http://%20https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-saferoom
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62589479/4694013

Answer (score -2):

By default Room store data in the app's internal storage which any root user can access.

**To secure encrypt Room database in android** you need to use encryption lib like this [cwac-saferoom](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-saferoom).

Comment: please, can you clarify exactly how you were able to use saferoom to encrypt your Room Database?